# Disable/Enable multiple buttons inside ngFor with a condition on ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, button

I have a list of buttons which needs to be enabled/disabled based on a condition at once two or three buttons may be disabled.

```
<li *ngFor="let button of buttons; let i = index">
   <button *ngIf="disableButtonIndex  && i+1 == disableButtonIndex" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled> {{ button.title }}</button>
   <button *ngIf="!(disableButtonIndex  && i+1 == disableButtonIndex)" (click)="callAction(button.actionName || i)" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">{{ button.title }}</button>
</li>
```

.ts

```
this.disableButtonIndex = 1;
```

Above code works fine for disabling single button how can i disable two/more buttons

Comment: Is the `disableButtonIndex` supposed to have more than one index on it?

Comment: yes it can but how?

Comment: Is it dynamically then?

Comment: @developer033 not dynamic,disableButtonIndex can be conditional for single button disabling i can pass one value to deal.How can disable multiple buttons in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array to save your disabled indexes or add the disabled flag in your button option.

## Use disabled array

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sef3nc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  disabledButtons= [1, 2]

  buttons = [
    {
      actionName: 'action1',
      title: 'button1'
    },
    {
      actionName: 'action2',
      title: 'button2'
    },
    {
      actionName: 'action3',
      title: 'button3'
    }
  ]

  callAction(action) {
    console.log(action)
  }
}
```

```html
<li *ngFor="let button of buttons; let i = index">
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
           [disabled]="disabledButtons.indexOf(i) !== -1"
           (click)="callAction(button.actionName)"> 
           {{ button.title }}
   </button>
</li>
```

## Use flag in option

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvbepr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  buttons = [
    {
      actionName: 'action1',
      title: 'button1',
      disabled: true
    },
    {
      actionName: 'action2',
      title: 'button2',
      disabled: true
    },
    {
      actionName: 'action3',
      title: 'button3',
      disabled: false
    }
  ]

  callAction(action) {
    console.log(action)
  }
}
```

```html
<li *ngFor="let button of buttons; let i = index">
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
           [disabled]="button.disabled"
           (click)="callAction(button.actionName)"> 
           {{ button.title }}
   </button>
</li>
```

Comment: Not sure that's what the OP wants, because I still don't get it, however as an advice, you could avoid call `functions` in templates, like this: `disabledButtons.indexOf(i) !== -1"`. Instead you could just create an `object` to map the disabled buttons, like this: `readonly disabledButtonsMapper = { 1: true, 2: false, 3: true };` and in template: `[disabled]="disabledButtonsMapper[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of *ngIf you can use [disabled]="expressionToEvaluate"

```js
<li *ngFor="let button of buttons; let i = index">
   <button [disabled]="disableButtonIndex  && i+1 == disableButtonIndex" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"> {{ button.title }}</button>
   <button [disabled]="!(disableButtonIndex  && i+1 == disableButtonIndex)" (click)="callAction(button.actionName || i)" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">{{ button.title }}</button>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, But the functionality results in the same disabling a single button.

Comment: Is correct that only one be disabled, because the two expressions are exactly opposite.

Comment: Right,How can i disable multiple buttons inside loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with next iteration buttons inside li element.

You can store all disable button indexes in an array and check current index exists in array.

```
<li *ngFor="let button of buttons; let i = index">
   <button [disabled]="disableButtonArr.indexOf((i+1)) === -1" (click)="callAction(button.actionName || i)" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">{{ button.title }}</button>
</li>
```